# How to sum dictionaries values with same key inside a list?

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
list1 = [
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 10},
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 12},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 11},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 15},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 17},
    {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 13},
]
```

How do I combine the dictionaries so I get this list from list1?

```
list2 = [
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 22},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 43},
    {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 13},
]
```

Comment: Why a list of dicts? How about `{"USD": 22, "EUR": 43, ...}`?

Comment: list2 is the response of an api call and its is required to be in this form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Counter` to calculate the summs

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for d in list1:
    cur, v = d.get('currency'), d.get('value')
    c.update({cur: v})

print(c)
Counter({'EUR': 43, 'USD': 22, 'GBP': 13})
```

and after generate the output:

```
list2 = [{'currency': cur, 'value': v} for cur, v in c.items()]
print(list2)
[{'currency': 'USD', 'value': 22}, {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 13}, {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 43}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for x in list1:
     c, v = x["currency"], x["value"]
     d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + v
# {'EUR': 43, 'GBP': 13, 'USD': 22}
```

Then either use that dict directly (I would recommend that) or turn it back into your list-of-dicts format, use a list-comprehension:

```
>>> [{"currency": k, "value": v} for k, v in d.items()]
[{'currency': 'USD', 'value': 22},
 {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 43},
 {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 13}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
list1 = [
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 10},
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 12},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 11},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 15},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 17},
    {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 13},
]

valuePairs = {}

for d in list1:
    curr = d['currency']
    val = d['value']

    if curr in valuePairs:
        valuePairs[curr] += val
    else:
        valuePairs[curr] = val

solution = [{'currency': k, 'value': v} for k, v in valuePairs.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.defaultdict`.

**Demo:**

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
list1 = [
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 10},
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 12},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 11},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 15},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 17},
    {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 13},
]
for i in list1:
    d[i['currency']] += i["value"]

print( [{'currency': k, 'value': v} for k,v in d.items()] )
```

**Output:**

```
[{'currency': 'USD', 'value': 22}, {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 13}, {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 43}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do:

```
import itertools as it
list1 = [
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 10},
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 12},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 11},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 15},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 17},
    {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 13},
]

kfunc = lambda x: x['currency']

groups = it.groupby(sorted(list1, key=kfunc), kfunc)
result = [{'currency':k, 'value':sum(x['value'] for x in g)} for k, g in groups]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also one-line it:

```
[{"currency": k, "value": sum([d["value"] for d in list1 if d["currency"] == k])} for k in list(set([d["currency"] for d in list1]))]
```

`list(set([d["currency"] for d in list1]))` gives you the unique list of currencies

You sum then values of each unique currency to make the new dict.

Comment: Personally, I think this is one of those cases where a one-liner does _not_ make it easier. Also, this is O(n²), which _might_ be an issue is the lists are (considerably) larger.